# Save user language in a model through default() with Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to save the language of the user each time a new model instance is created:

models.py:

```
def getlanguage(request):
    lang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    return lang


class Comment(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=getlanguage)
```

Django generates the following error:
TypeError: getlanguage() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

How to pass the request to the function?

Thank you!

Comment: request object is received in the views. You have to do it from there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have many different views creating instances. now way to automate that ?

Comment: you can write a model method. and pass request as argument.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ? I cannot manage to have it working

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your save method needs to be overridden like this.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_language = kwargs.pop('default_language', None)
        if not self.language and default_language is not None:
            self.language = default_language
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And you can pass the parameter when save() is called on an object in the views

```
comment = Comment()
comment.save(default_language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep. But I cannot have it work automatically without calling it from the view, correct ?